# C: How do i go about gaining access to a full terminal window on a *nix system

Tags: c, text-editor, tui

I am planning on writing a command line text editor in C for a *nix system similar to nano or vim but I am stuck on how I would go about getting access to the entire terminal window so the user can move around the text editor freely, do I need to use a 3rd party library to achieve this result if so what libraries are required, or am I able to achieve this result with the standard C libraries and if so what libraries should I use.

Comment: You probably want [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: "do I need to use a 3rd party library". No you don't have to if you want to do everything from first principles. But that's going to be a lot of work. Generally people use a terminal lib like [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ncurses library is the simplest way of gaining access to a full terminal window although it can also be achieved with the libc libraries.